# Como alterar local de salvamento getRealPath() ? Photocam primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, netbeans

Estou tentando utilizar o componente Photocam do Primefaces, está funcionando, porem a imagem é salva dentro do target da aplicação.
Quero mudar o local de salvamento.
Segue um trecho do código.

```
   ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String newFileName = externalContext.getRealPath("") + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "photocam" + File.separator + filename + ".jpeg";
```

Agradeço muito se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Primeiro você precisa ler o arquivo
- Segundo você precisa saber onde quer salvar o novo arquivo
- Terceiro você precisa copiar ou recortar o arquivo para o novo local
- Eu gosto de usar a lib do apache, FileUtils é simples e fácil de usar

Abaixo tem um method que uso para fazer isso

```
public static File changeUploadedFileInFile(UploadedFile fileOld, String pathSaveFile) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(pathSaveFile);
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    try
    {
        FileUtils.forceMkdir(file);
        file = new File(pathSaveFile + fileOld.getFileName());
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        input = fileOld.getInputstream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1)
        {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        return file;
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        LOG.error(SysUtilLogLevel.ERROR, "Error close stream file importer", e);
        throw new IOException();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (outputStream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                LOG.error(MarkerFactory.getMarker("error"), "Error close stream file importer", e);
            }
        }
        if (input != null)
        {
            try
            {
                input.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                LOG.error(MarkerFactory.getMarker("error"), "Error close stream file importer", e);
            }
        }
```

Esse method esta criando um arquivo novo na pathSaveFile, e copiando o arquivo velho para dentro do novo arquivo. Não excluir o velho arquivo se ele existe. mas você nem precisa salvar pode usar o Stream direto da memória, se os arquivos não forem muito grande.

Comment: Cara deu certo, fiz da seguinte forma
        String newFileName = externalContext.getRealPath("..\\..\\src\\main\\webapp\\resources\\algaworks\\images\\") + File.separator + filename + ".jpeg";

Obrigado

Comment: Marca como certo a resposta e da um voto nela, pra indexar e ajudar outras pessoas